# Starting other Application directly

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to run another Application (Polaris Office) directly from my Application. But it should open a PDF File directly too.

I tried the following Code:

```
File targetFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/pdf.pdf");
Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.infraware.PolarisOfficeForTablet",
                                      "com.infraware.viewer.UxViewerActivity"));
intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");

startActivity(intent);
```

Any Idea how i can do that? My current code gives the Errormessage:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/pdf.pdf
>   typ=application/pdf
>   cmp=com.infraware.PolarisOfficeForTablet/com.infraware.viewer.UxViewerActivity
>   } from ProcessRecord{40bc9598 10349:de.pixelstein.nativ/10099}
>   (pid=10349, uid=10099) not exported from uid 10040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only start activities of other applications if they has been marked in their `AndroidManifest.xml` as exported or that has an  `<intent-filter>` defined which exports them automatically.

Comment: But how can i open a file directly in one Application without setting one Application "as Standard"?